# Granular error handling in Passport authenticate

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am authenticating a user in a REST call and I implement a custom callback as explained in the docs.

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    //.. do something with user here and send a response
  })(req, res, next); 
});
```

Now I would like to pass an error if some validation failed in the strategy.

```
passport.use(new BasicStrategy(
function(email, password, callback) {

User.findOne({
  email: email
}, function(err, user) {
  if (err) {
    return callback(err);
  }

  if (!user) {
    return callback(new Error('User unknown'), false);
  }

  // Make sure the password is correct
  user.verifyPassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }

    // Password did not match
    if (!isMatch) {
      return callback(new Error('Password mismatch'), false);
    }

    // Success
    return callback(null, user);
  });
});
```

}

But the error is never passed to the callback in `authenticate`:

```
function(err, user, info) {
     // err is always null
}
```

How can I pass an error so I can give more granuate feedback to users?

Answer (score 0):

I found two issues with your code. The first one is that you request for 'local' authentication strategy while you register a BasicStrategy. In order to do that you should replace 'local' with 'basic'.

The second one is that, if you want to use the BasicStrategy, you have to use the Base Authentication supported by the HTTP protocol, otherwise the BasicStrategy's callback will not be called and your authentication callback will run with err == null and user == false.

I tested this with Postman, and only after I sent Basic Auth info, did the BasicStrategy callback run.

I hope this helps.